# Geospatial and Morphia not find by near

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial, morphia

I have the following database:

> db.ItemVo.find()
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("55bf2b465ef98ff39dba049c"), "loc" : { "type" :
>   "Point", "coordinates" : [ -4.427237, 36.733284 ] }, "title" :
>   "item1", "summary" :  "Summary item1", "itemType" : "TXT" } { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("55bf2ddc5ef98ff39dba049d"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point",
>   "coordinates" : [ -3.427237, 35.733284 ] }, "title" : "item2",
>   "summary" :  "Summary item2", "itemType" : "TXT" }

Find by $near:

> db.ItemVo.find({loc:{"$near":{ "$geometry": {type: "Point",
>   coordinates: [-4.427, 36.73]}, "$maxDistance": 20000}}})
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("55bf2b465ef98ff39dba049c"), "loc" : { "type" :
>   "Point", "coordinates" : [ -4.427237, 36.733284 ] }, "title" :
>   "item1", "summary" :  "Summary item1", "itemType" : "TXT" }

In Morphia DAO:

```
public List<ItemVo> findByNear (){
    LOGGER.info("[ItemDAO - findByNear] - init");

    List<ItemVo> str = getDs().find(ItemVo.class).field("loc").near(-4.427, 36.73,  2000/111.12, true).asList();
    return str;
}
```

Morphia returns all elements of the collection and not finds by $near. Morphia should return only the element "item1" and not the "item2". Where is the problem?

My Objects:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
Public class ItemVo implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1258690003100456384L;

        @Id private String id;

        @Embedded
        private LocationVo loc;

        private String title;
        private String summary;
```

........

```
@Embedded
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class LocationVo implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5282690346503247312L;

    private String type; //POINT, etc
    private double[] coordinates;
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently solved it and want to put the solution to other people with the same question. I don´t know why it works now, perhaps because I use a newer version of Morphia. Mi code:

```
public List<ItemVo> findItems (Double latitude, Double longitude, Double radius){
    LOGGER.info("[ItemDAO - findItems] - init");
    str = getDs().createQuery(ItemVo.class).field("loc").near(latitude, longitude,  radius/111.12, true).asList();
    return str;
}
```

In webservice is received the parameter "radius" (Integer, in kilometers) and we transform it before calling itemDAO.findItems:

```
//private static Double FORMAT_RADIUS = 0.01;

Double radius_format = radius * FORMAT_RADIUS;
```

Comment: I would say, that latitude/longitude should be swapped. According to [this](https://morphia.dev/1.4/javadoc/dev/morphia/query/FieldEnd.html#near-double-double-boolean-) it is `longitude` first, followed by `latitude`.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I've tracked it down and it's simple.  For reasons which escape me, the mongo shell takes coordinates in lat/long and morphia takes them in long/lat.  So while it *looks* like you're faithfully recreating the query in morphia, you actually have your coordinates defined backwards.  Try swapping your values and you should start seeing the documents you expect.

Answer (score 0):

@evanchooly not work. Currently data:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("55bf2b465ef98ff39dba049c"), "loc" : { "type" :
>   "Point", "coordinates" : [ -4.427237, 36.733284 ] },  "title" :
>   "item1", "summary" : "Summary item1", "itemType" : "TXT"} { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("55bf2ddc5ef98ff39dba049d"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point",
>   "coordinates" : [ -3.427237, 35.733284 ] },  "title" : "item2",
>   "summary" : "Summary item2", "itemType" : "TXT"} { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("55bf419d79711904641950e3"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point",
>   "coordinates" : [ -2.427237, 36.733284 ] },  "title" : "item3",
>   "summary" : "Summary item3", "itemType" : "TXT"} { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("55bf74bd7971191d180d67ad"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point",
>   "coordinates" : [ -5.427237, 35.733284 ] },  "title" : "item4",
>   "summary" : "Summary item4", "itemType" : "TXT"}

```
geo[0]=-4.4272;
geo[1]=36.733;
```

With lat/long (as it was before) Morphia returns all elements although the radius is 2/111.12 or 20000/111.12.

With long/lat as you said, Morphia returns empty list with radius from 2/111.12 to 107/111.12. With radius 108/111.12 returns item2 and item3. With radius from 109/111.12 to 20000/111.12 returns all elements.

I don´t undestand why. I think that maybe the query of Morphia is not well and Morphia doesn´t find "loc", so Morphia returns all. I have been searching google and the query should be fine.

EDIT:

If I run the following command in mongo console:

```
db.runCommand ( {geoNear: "ItemVo", near : [-4.427, 36.733 ] , maxDistance: 20000, spherical:true })
```

Each returned element contains the distance. For example:

> { "dis" : 0.00000596312302919342, "obj" : { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("55bf2b465ef98ff39dba049c"), ... ... } },

I don´t undestand why the distance values are different than the call:

```
db.ItemVo.find({loc:{"$near":{ "$geometry": {type: "Point", coordinates: [-4.427, 36.73]}, "$maxDistance": 20000}}})
```

Comment: Morphia doesn't do anything of the kind.  It passes your query to the server and returns whatever the server does.  It doesn't just decide things about your data.  I'm not a geo guy but those radii seem a bit small to me so I'm not entirely surprised nothing comes back for the smaller values.

Comment: (I edited my answer with this comment) If I run the following command in mongo console: db.runCommand ( {geoNear: "ItemVo", near : [-4.427, 36.733 ] , maxDistance: 20000, spherical:true }) Each returned element contains the distance. For example: 
{ "dis" : 0.00000596312302919342, "obj" : { "_id" : ObjectId("55bf2b465ef98ff39dba049c"), ... ... } }, 

I don´t undestand why the distance values are different than the call:

db.ItemVo.find({loc:{"$near":{ "$geometry": {type: "Point", coordinates: [-4.427, 36.73]}, "$maxDistance": 20000}}})

Comment: I think the difference is the `spherical: true`.  Either don't pass that or set it to false and see what difference that makes.  (I'm not a geo guy so I'm dredging up what random tidbits I've heard over the years.)